# Load multiple tables in parallel

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, toad

I have 10 tables and they are connected to 10 different source tables. Basically I am truncating target tables and then doing bulk insert from each source to individual target tables.

Eg: Src_A --->Tgt_A
Src_B ---> Tgt_B

Each "Insert into tgt select * from src" statement is running in loop one after another. Is it possible to make all the statements run in parallel in one single procedure like when data is getting loaded in Tgt_A it should also be loading data in to Tgt_B.

Appreciate your valuable inputs.

Dex.

Comment: You'd need to run separate jobs in parallel through the scheduler; maybe chained so you wait for them all to complete.

Comment: Yeah that we can do but is it possible in one single procedure I load tables in parallel ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use Parallel Execution Tuning from Oracle. It basically parallelizes a query, but not parallelize between different queries.

This is how the PARALLEL hint is used. INSERT and SELECT can be parallel independently:

```
alter session enable parallel dml;

INSERT /*+ PARALLEL(4) */ INTO tbl_ins
    SELECT * FROM tbl_sel;
```

To make N queries parallel, you would need N different connections to the database, each one executing a different query.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has DBMS_JOB which can suffice your requirement. Basically when you submit the jobs, Oracle will trigger all the jobs paralllely since reducing overall time for execution.
Hope below snippet helps.

```
DECLARE
lv_job1 PLS_INTEGER;
lv_job2 PLS_INTEGER;
lv_job3 PLS_INTEGER;
lv_job4 PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  DBMS_JOB.submit ( lv_job1, 'BEGIN
                              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''TRUNCATE TABLE TGT1'';
                              INSERT INTO SRC1
                              SELECT * FROM SELEC_TAB;
                              END;
                              ');

    DBMS_JOB.submit ( lv_job2, 'BEGIN
                              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''TRUNCATE TABLE TGT2'';
                              INSERT INTO SRC2
                              SELECT * FROM SELEC_TAB;
                              END;
                              ');

     DBMS_JOB.submit ( lv_job3, 'BEGIN
                              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''TRUNCATE TABLE TGT3'';
                              INSERT INTO SRC3
                              SELECT * FROM SELEC_TAB;
                              END;
                              ');

    DBMS_JOB.submit ( lv_job4, 'BEGIN
                              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''TRUNCATE TABLE TGT4'';
                              INSERT INTO SRC4
                              SELECT * FROM SELEC_TAB;
                              END;
                              ');
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: I liked this idea but when I tried am getting this issue "ora-06550 pls-00201 DBMS_JOB must be declared" ... Is this procedure is accessible only by DBAs?? Can normal Oracle Users do this similar functionality without needing dba grants??

Comment: DBA must grant execute access on DBMS_JOB package to your user. Its a good idea to use this kind of approach.